# I use Rigify metahuman for rigging my character in Blender. Is there a way to capture motion using live video from my webcam?

Tags: motion-capture

Rigify is a great addon for rigging character inside blender. But the problem is animating the characters is not very easy using the handles generated by rigify. 
I tried downloading bvh files from some University websites which has a lot of motion capture data. But whenever I import the bvh file, a new rig is also imported. I don't want this to happen as I already have rigged my character using rigify addon.
I am aware of of some motion capture techniques using open CV library in python. I can do some amount of programming but not so much that it can generate the script which I need to map the live motion to the character.

Is there a better way to map the live motion using webcam or video to the rig generated using rigify addon inside of blender